# Error when using insert with CTE and ranking function

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, ranking

I have a table temp.Results which contain Employee info. This table contains info used by HR. All changes to the employee records are in the table.i.e.

```
select * from temp.Results where ID=1
1,'2 main st','salem','2009-01-01','2000-01-01'
1,'34 elm st','acton','2013-03-09','2000-01-01'
```

Datevalidated is when we entered latest info.DateProcessed is the first time we entered employee info.

```
 WITH ordered as( 
select ID, name, address,city, DateValidated, DateProcessed
,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by DateValidated
       order by DateValidated desc) as rn from 
  aa.temp.Results (nolock) where id=31  
  ) 
  insert into tempResults2(ID, name, address,city, DateValidated, DateProcessed)
select ID, name, address,city, DateValidated, DateProcessed from ordered where rn = 1 ;
```

I tried getting the above query to get the latest info of each employee into a teable but get this error.

```
Invalid object name 'tempResults2'
```

How to resolve this?

Thanks
MR

Comment: What is `tempresults2`? Does this table exist? Your first query talks about `temp.results` with no reference to `tempresults2`?

Comment: tempresults2 is a temp table, that is not created but iam trying to create it on the run just like we do,.. Select * into tempresults2 from temp.Results; But this would copy over whole table

Comment: In that case, you should be using `select into`. see answer I have posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `where` clause with `select * into` .

```
WITH ordered as
( 
    select 
        ID, name, address,city, DateValidated, DateProcessed,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by DateValidated order by DateValidated desc) as rn 
    from aa.temp.Results  where id=31  
  ) 

select * into tempResults2 from ordered where rn = 1 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH ordered as( 
select ID, name, address,city, DateValidated, DateProcessed
,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by DateValidated
       order by DateValidated desc) as rn from 
  aa.temp.Results (nolock) where id=31  
  ) 
  select ID, name, address,city, DateValidated, DateProcessed 
  into tempResults2 
  from ordered 
  where rn = 1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You query is wrong. When you can use nolock like this

```
WITH ordered as( 
select ID, name, address,city, DateValidated, DateProcessed
,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by DateValidated
       order by DateValidated desc) as rn from 
  aa.temp.Results with(nolock) where id=31  
  )
```

Comment: I use sql server 2008 I don't need to use 'with (nolock)'

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'nolock'. If this is intended as a part of a table hint, A WITH keyword and parenthesis are now required. See SQL Server Books Online for proper syntax.

Comment: I run my queries all the time with just (nolock).